# How do I specify the number of rows and columns to print multiple plots per page with gridExtra?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, pdf-generation, gridextra

I have created a number of plots through a for loop using `ggplot`, and saved each plot into a list `plots`.

```
plots <- list()

for (i in 1:238)

{

    gene <- row.names(geneExpression)[i]

    df.sub <- df[ , c("source", gene)]

    names(test.sub) <- c("source", "exp")

    plots[[i]] <- ggplot() + geom_violin(data=test.sub, aes(source, exp, fill=source, color=source), alpha=.4, trim=F, environment = environment()) + coord_flip() + ggtitle(gene) + theme(legend.position="none") + labs(x="")

}
```

I am using the gridExtra function as suggested elsewhere, but when I do this, it prints all of the plots (240 plots) in a single page.

```
pdf("violinPlots.pdf")
do.call(grid.arrange, plots)
dev.off()
```

Is there a way I can specify that I want 24 plots per page? (i.e. 6 rows x 4 columns?)

I tried this but it returns an error...

```
grid.arrange(plots, ncol=4, newpage = T )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gridExtra's [marrangeGrob](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/gridExtra/html/marrangeGrob.html) function:

```
pdf("violinPlots.pdf")
ml <- marrangeGrob(grobs = plots, nrow = 6, ncol = 4)
print(ml)
dev.off()
```